# How does Bitpay.com getting transactions info as its open source?

Tags: bitpay

How does Bitpay.com wallet getting transactions info and listing unspents?

Are they connecting to Electrum servers peers or are they connecting to their servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wallet connects to a server running bitcore software. This is software that provides an API for the wallet to use to get data about transactions on the blockchain. By default the server it connects to is run by bitpay. Bitpay sees all your addresses and transactions.

Comment: is it possible to connect to that server and get special address balance?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your transaction's confirmation status and other payment details on any blockchain explorer (like BitPay's block explorer Insight). Look up your transaction using your transaction ID or the sending or receiving bitcoin addresses, which can all be found in your bitcoin wallet that sent the payment. For your transaction to be considered fully confirmed by most BitPay merchants, your transaction will need to have six confirmations.

More info: https://insight.bitpay.com/

Comment: I guess he is not asking about how to check a transaction ID, he would know how Bitpay checking address unspent or transactions in their app, for example in electrum blockchain. blockchain.address.get_history RPC command